# Home network 2 subnets

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

Network noob here. This is my current home network situation:

[image: 1]

So I have two ISPs, one VDSL the other over TV cable. Each one has a router with WiFi and an ethernet switch attached to it. Several devices connect to the switches, so I basically have to subnets 192.168.178.x and 192.168.0.x. My questions:

How can I enable the devices from each subnet (and floor level in my situation) to talk to each other?
E.g. Device A1 and Device B1? I need some connection between the nets and probably have to turn off one of the DHCP servers? Do I need another router?

Comment: Could you provided the model of the routers and available ports on each?

Comment: VDSL: fritzBox 7530, 4 LAN Ports, Cable: TC7200, 4 LAN Ports

Answer (score 1):

If both routers are simple home routers that have one WAN and one LAN interface (the router may have a switch built-in so physically there may be more than one LAN port, but they are not visible as separate interfaces by router, they are just "multiplied" on switch), then yes, you need another router.

If one of your routers has an additional interface (for example "DMZ" interface that some better "home office" type routers have), then you can use that interface to interconnect the networks.

You don't need to remove any of the DHCP servers, as DHCP server only works for it's network, ie. up to the router. DHCP packets are not forwarded across the routers unless you configure the routers specially to do so (and simple routers usually don't have the feature at all).

I will describe three variants here:

1. you have "DMZ" interface on both routers
2. you have "DMZ" interface on one router
3. you don't have "DMZ" interface on any of the routers

The above are listed in increasing configuration difficulty order :)

In case 1:

- connect the DMZ interfaces of both routers to each other
- configure the IP address of the DMZ interfaces to some network different from both of your current networks. Let's say, the router upstairs will be 192.268.200.1, and the router downstairs will be 192.168.200.2. Netmask should be 255.255.255.0 or 24 bits (depending on what notation your router uses).
- no DHCP on these interfaces
- in router upstairs, you must manually add to the routing table a route to the network 192.168.0.0/24 (or 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0) going through gateway 192.168.200.2
- similarly, in router downstairs, you must add a route to the network 192.168.178.0/24 through gateway 192.168.200.1
- as devices in both your networks have default gateway set to their appropriate router, they should be able to reach each other now

In case 2:

Let's assume that the router upstairs has a DMZ interface and the router downstairs doesn't have one. You can just symetrically do it the other way if it's otherwise.

- connect the DMZ interface of the upstairs router to a free port in the downstairs switch (you must have one, if you don't, you need another switch)
- configure the DMZ interface on router upstairs to some unused address from the downstairs network - let it for example be 192.168.0.200. It's best if the address can be excluded from DHCP range on the downstairs router. Netmask 255.255.255.0 or 24 bits as above
- now the devices in your upstairs network should be able to send packets to devices on downstairs network via their default gateway, but the devices on downstairs network don't know how to talk back to them! - so there is no connection
- you can try to solve it in two ways. First, you can try to configure in your downstairs router a route to 192.168.178.0/24 through gateway 192.168.0.200. But this might not work as it requires that the router supports so called "router on a stick" functionality which not all routers can do.
- If it doesn't work, here comes the difficult part. You must manually add on EVERY device in the downstairs network a static permanent route to network 192.168.178.0/255.255.255.0 (or /24) via gateway 192.168.0.200. It depends of course on the operating system how exactly to do it.

In case 3:

Start with buying another router. When choosing a router, check if it is able to connect two networks **without** performing NAT (Network Address Translation). On some simple models of home routers the NAT functionality can't be turned off - these routers are useless to you.

You'll also need free ports on both switches. If you don't have them, you need additional switches.

- connect one interface of the new router to the free port on upstairs switch, another interface to the free port on downstairs switch. NAT and DHCP on the new router must be turned off.
- assign to the interface which is connected upstairs an unused IP address from the upstairs network - let's say 192.168.178.200. Similarly, assign to the interface that is connected downstairs an unused address from the downstairs network (192.168.0.200). Netmask 255.255.255.0 or 24 as previously. If possible, exclude these addresses from DHCP ranges on both your routers respectively.
- You will again have the "router on a stick" issue, but this time with both routers. First, try to configure a route to 192.168.0.0/24 via gateway 192.168.178.200 on the upstairs router and a route to 192.168.178.0/24 via gateway 192.168.0.200 on downstairs router.
- If this doesn't work, you need to configure on EVERY device on the upstairs network a route to the network 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 (or /24) via gateway 192.168.178.200, and on EVERY device on the downstairs network a route to the network 192.168.178.0/255.255.255.0 (or /24) via gateway 192.168.0.200

Comment: Case 3 looks attractive to me - do you have a recommendation for the additional router? Which keywords would led me to the right results on google?

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't bought a router for a long time, so can't recommend anything.

Comment: If you have a computer that runs constantly 24/7, you can try to use it as a router by adding an additional network card to it.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level you will need to do the following(assuming these routers have this functionality)

- configure a second lan on a free port on one of your routers
- ensure dhcp is disabled for this new lan and set the ip of the router to a free address in the other network
- connect the the port assigned to the newly created lan to the other network
- on each router configure a new static route that will route traffic destin to the other lan to the ip address of the router response for this network

I will tidy this up later on